# python のフォルダの書き込み順に関しまして

Tags: python

python のフォルダの書き込み順に関してお聞きしたいのですが、
以下のサンプルを実行しますと、

```
import os

def asxmake(srcDir):
    for sub in os.listdir(srcDir):
        newSrcPath = os.path.join(srcDir, sub)
        if os.path.isdir(newSrcPath):
            f = open(AsxMake, 'a+')
            print >>f, sub
            print sub
            asxmake(newSrcPath)

        else:
            f = open(AsxMake, 'a+')
            file = sub.replace('/','\\')
            filename = os.path.basename(file)
            print >>f, sub
            print sub

srcDir = 'C:\\temp\\test'
AsxMakefol = 'C:\\temp\\test'
AsxMake = 'C:\\temp\\test\\1.asx'
asxmake(srcDir)
```

書き込まれたファイルを確認してみると、

（一番上の階層は、01.txt 02.txt
00フォルダ構造の中に03.txt 04.txtがある状態でテストしています。）

03.txt
04.txt
00
01.txt
02.txt
となってしまいます。

print文で確認すると処理順は以下のようになっている
のですが、
00
03.txt
04.txt
01.txt
02.txt
何が原因で順番が変わってしまうのでしょうか？

program初心者のため、解決策を見出せません。
ご教授の程よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 6):

ファイルはバッファリングしていることを念頭に置くと理解しやすいです。
バッファリングとは、ファイルに書き出す前にメモリに貯めておき、一定量たまったら、またはファイルがクローズされたら、ファイルに書き出します。

今回は、再帰しているので、再帰の中で出力したものが先に書きだされます。

```
00 => バッファ1
  03.txt => バッファ2
  04.txt => バッファ2         
  バッファ2書き出し
01.txt => バッファ1
02.txt => バッファ1
バッファ1書き出し
```

バッファ2、バッファ1の順番で書き出されるので、記載どおりの結果になります。
コレを解消するには、一つには、flush を使う方法があります。

```
def asxmake(srcDir):
    for sub in os.listdir(srcDir):
        newSrcPath = os.path.join(srcDir, sub)
        if os.path.isdir(newSrcPath):
            f = open(AsxMake, 'a+')
            print >>f, sub
            f.flush()
            print sub
            asxmake(newSrcPath)
        else:
            f = open(AsxMake, 'a+')
            file = sub.replace('/','\\')
            filename = os.path.basename(file)
            print >>f, sub
            f.flush()
            print sub
```

しかしながら、ファイルを毎回開かない、かつ、walk を使うほうが楽な気がします。

Comment: user3758624様

ご返答ありがとうございます。
頂いた内容で理解できました！

迅速に回答を頂け誠に感謝しております。

もしお時間よろしければお聞きしたいのですが、
walkの方は以前一度使ったことがあるのでどのようなものかは、
わかるのですが、ファイルを毎回開かない方法とはどのようなものでしょうか？
そのような方法も考えたのですが、、
力不足のためこのような方法をとっておりました。

お手数ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @chandler kaoz forループ内で`f`が最初に定義され、次のループで同じスコープにある`f`が再度定義されると、先のfはそこでクローズになります。クローズされるとバッファの内容がディスクに書き込まれるのでバッファの問題と言えなくはありませんが。変数のスコープにもっと気を使ったほうがいいでしょう。そもそも同じファイルを同時に開いているので、結果がdeterministic(決定的？）でないです。flushを使っても厳密には保証されないです。f.flush()するより本来f.close()すべきでしょう。

Answer (score 4):

ファイルを一度開いたら、同じファイルハンドラを使って書き込むようにすれば解決できます。

```
import os

def asxmake(f, srcDir):
    for sub in os.listdir(srcDir):
        newSrcPath = os.path.join(srcDir, sub)
        if os.path.isdir(newSrcPath):
            print >>f, sub
            asxmake(f, newSrcPath)

        else:
            file = sub.replace('/','\\')
            filename = os.path.basename(file)
            print >>f, sub

srcDir = 'C:\\temp\\test'
AsxMakefol = 'C:\\temp\\test'
AsxMake = 'C:\\temp\\test\\1.asx'

with open(AsxMake, 'w') as f:
    asxmake(f, srcDir)
```

Comment: Kenji Noguchi様
ご返答いただきありがとうございます。非常に勉強になりました。このような書き方があるのですね。全く想像もしておりませんでした。
初心者のため１つのことを覚えると覚えたことでどうしても済ませようとしてしまいレベルが上がらないということを痛感しました。
f.closeはどこかの記事でpythonでは、自動的にcloseするということを読み、勘違いし使わないようになっておりました。本質を理解できていなかったと思います。
いろいろな助言を頂けたこと感謝しております。ありがとうございました。

Comment: `f`が消滅するとき自動的にcloseするのは正しい理解です。ただ、今回のコードではフォルダの階層を一つ下がるごとに再帰していますから、再帰する前の`f`と再帰先の`f`は別の関数スコープなので、別ものです。`print id(f)`とするとオブジェクトのidが表示されるので`f`が別ものであることを確認できます。再帰前の`f`は再帰から帰ってくるまで生きていますから、ファイルは開きっぱなしになるわけです。

Comment: 上のコメントは「トピ主さん掲載のオリジナルコードでの再帰する前のfと再帰‌​先のfは別の関数スコープ」という意味です。念のため。

Comment: Kenji Noguchi様 度々のご返答誠にありがとうございます。
頂いた内容理解できました！
重ね重ね御礼申し上げます。